# GO debug configuration in Intellij

Tags: go, intellij-idea

How do I solve the following: when trying to debug a GO project in Intelllij, an error message appears saying "Module does not exist in project." Then when I click "debug anyway," an error message says that Go isn't configured for the run configuration. I tried deleting the .idea file but that doesn't help. In the configuration window, no module appears in the dropdown.

Comment: Did you init the project with `go mod init example`?

Comment: Could you please share screenshots of the full IDEA window showing your project structure and `File | Project Structure | Modules` which might include some clues?

Comment: I looked there and saw there was no module and added it, and it worked